# Using StringTokenizer to do This

Tags: java

I need to use StringTokenizer to search through a string, and if they find this two words in the string, they will print "Yes.", if not, it'll print "No."

These two words are "eat", and "yet", and the string is "Did you eat yet?"
If it finds both words in that string it's suppose to print out yes, and if not, it's suppose to print out no. I have no idea how to do this. If you do, then please help.

Comment: Can't help if you don't have any code.

Comment: Why are you using StringTokenizer though. Using StringTokenizer is discouraged. You should use Regex instead.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Is that a school assignment? You should try and come up with an attempted solution yourself. Ask specific questions if you get stuck at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Did you eat yet?");
```

This is how you initialize a StringTokenizer. Then your implementation should use the .hasMoreTokens() method to step through the tokens and check if they are equal to the words you are searching for.

Not sure why would want to use this method however, as..

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

From the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, using StringTokenizer is discouraged and in this case is over complicating the procedure in the first place.

Getting familiar with the Java [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class is the right start. Here we find it's possible to determine if a string `contains()` the target string with `yourString.contains(yourSubString)`.

You can combine this with another call to `contains()` in a conditional with...

`if (yourString.contains(someSubString) && 
     yourString.contains(someOtherSubString)) { ... }`

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Is it also possible to make it IgnoreCase? Something like equalsIgnoreCase?

Comment: Try it like this. `"HELLO WORLD".toLowerCase().contains("hello");` returns `true`. @nmelssx There's `compareToIgnoreCase()` but that's going to compare the entire string to you sub, so not really without changing it to strip the word out anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I just use toLowerCase() to make the whole string lowercase, and then just use the contain() method.

Comment: Yep; hat's right. @nmelssx